# must be real number, not Tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to compute the value of bit error rate by using erfc ,but the following error occurs,how I can solve this?

```
effSNR = cfh.effectiveSNR(txSymbols, rxSymbols, one, reduce_axis)
BER=(2.0/np.log2(param.M))*(1.0-(1/math.sqrt(param.M)))* erfc(math.sqrt((2.0*np.log2(param.M)*effSNR)/(2.0*((param.M)-1.0))))
     
Type Error: must be real number, not Tensor
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should add some data and the packages you use in order to help people for answering your question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.